# How to center a kivy widget relative to an other in a BoxLayout?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Hej

I am looking for a easy way to center a TextInput vertical. The pseudo kv code looks like this:

```
ParamBox:
      orientation: 'horizontal'
      padding: 5
      spaceing: 5            
      Button:
          text: 'hello'
          size_hint_x: 0.25
      Slider:
          size_hint_x: 0.5
      TextInput:
          size_hint_x: 0.25
          size_hint_y: None
          height: sp(32)
```

It doesn't look good, if the TextInput is drawed at the bottom. The goal is to draw it centered to the slider line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following do what you want? The AnchorLayout centres the TextInput by default.

```
ParamBox:
      orientation: 'horizontal'
      padding: 5
      spacing: 5            
      Button:
          text: 'hello'
          size_hint_x: 0.25
      Slider:
          size_hint_x: 0.5
      AnchorLayout:
          size_hint_x: 0.25
          TextInput:
              size_hint_y: None
              height: sp(32)
```